# Generating duplicates with weights (python)

Tags: python, list, random, duplicates

I have the following list:

```
priority=['Emergency','High','Normal','Low']
```

I need to generate a list of 15000 values in the list above, with frequency of each of them being 10%,20%,30%,40%. Can somebody show me how to do it?

Comment: I've edited the question, my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [`choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) function of numpy.random.

```
import numpy as np

priority=['Emergency','High','Normal','Low']
b = np.random.choice(priority, 150, replace=True, p=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

print(b)
```

Built-in [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) does the same thing but it is not available <3.6.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use random.random(), and assign indexes based on the range of the random number.

```
In [21]: priority=['Emergency','High','Normal','Low']

In [22]: idx = lambda x: 0 if x < 0.1 else (1 if x < 0.3 else (2 if x < 0.6 else 3))

In [23]: import random

In [24]: [priority[idx(random.random())] for _ in range(15000)]
Out[24]: 
['Normal',
 'High',
 'Emergency',
 'Emergency',
 'High',
 .
 .
```

In the above, I've relied on the order of the elements within your list to generate indexes, such that for 0 to 0.1 it is the first (10%), 0.1 to 0.3 its the second (0.3 - 0.1 will cover 20%), and so on.